# Foundation 6 - Rows alignement in flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to center two div Horizontally, and align one at the Middle of the parent container, and the second one at the Bottom of the parent container. I'm using Foundation 6, with the Flexbox version.

**Html**

```
<section id="hero">
    <div class="row align-middle align-center">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row align-bottom align-center">
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Css**

```
#hero {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

The problem is that every div in the flex container (#hero) appear on the same line.

Thank's for helping !

Comment: I don't know about Foundation but with just flexbox will be something like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWedVV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how to align vertically 3 divs using a Flexbox. Foundation wasn't really in the problem.

I made a Js Fiddle for those who have the same question:

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height:90vh;
}
.center {
    width: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    align-items: center;
    display:flex;
}
.a {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="a">Header</div>
        <div class="center">Body</div>
        <div class="a">Footer</div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ek38ff5r/20/

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you have to add the class column to the sub element of row like so:

```
id="hero">
    <div class="row align-middle align-center">
        <h1 class="column">Welcome</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row align-bottom align-center">
        <p class="column">Some text</p>
    </div>
</section>
```